# Math.round works incorrectly

Tags: actionscript-2

I found that in Actionscript2, if `Math.round` does work when I do `Math.round(7.5)` and it gives me `8`,
but if I have an math expression which has a value `7.5` and apply `Math.round` to it, like:
`Math.round(value * 10)` (here value is 0.75),
instead of giving me `8`, it gives me `7`

Anyone know what exactly happened to it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a floating-point arithmetic problem.

Comment: @EdCottrell yes, I just don't know why it works with a number but fails with a math expression..

Comment: @DeveloperGuo Thanks for the link, but this is what I am trying to do - rounding to 1 decimal point. The function `toFixed` doesn't exist in Actionscript2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used the function on this page: http://ryanbosinger.com/blog/2008/flashactionscript-innaccurate-math-results/
the issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(val:Number):int {
  return Util.print(Math.round(val * 10));;
}   
test(.75);   //prints 8
```

Perhaps provide your code?

Comment: thanks, I use the function on this page: http://ryanbosinger.com/blog/2008/flashactionscript-innaccurate-math-results/ and it works